# Unable to validate token with OAuthPlayground application

Tags: oauth-2.0, pingfederate

I am new to PingFederate. I have setup the sample  OAuthPlayground web application on PingFederate 8.2.11 . To setup I imported the data.zip provided in the OAuthPlayground-3.3.0 . I am able to get a code . Subsequently I am able get the Access Token.  I can refresh the token even.

When I click on validate token, I get the following response :

{"error_description":"Invalid client or client credentials","error":"invalid_client"}

Please help as I am pretty stuck here.

Following are the excerpts from the server.log

2017-01-09 23:31:33,146  INFO  [com.pingidentity.ws.rest.oauth.client_management.filter.OAuthClientMgmtEnabledFilter] OAuth Client Management REST Web Service Attempted: service=/pf-ws/rest/oauth/clients, remote-ip=127.0.0.1, but the client management database is not enabled. Consult product documentation for config changes required to enable service.
2017-01-09 23:31:33,358  INFO  [com.pingidentity.ws.rest.oauth.client_management.filter.OAuthClientMgmtEnabledFilter] OAuth Client Management REST Web Service Attempted: service=/pf-ws/rest/oauth/clients, remote-ip=127.0.0.1, but the client management database is not enabled. Consult product documentation for config changes required to enable service.
2017-01-09 23:31:33,480  INFO  [com.pingidentity.ws.rest.oauth.client_management.filter.OAuthClientMgmtEnabledFilter] OAuth Client Management REST Web Service Attempted: service=/pf-ws/rest/oauth/clients, remote-ip=127.0.0.1, but the client management database is not enabled. Consult product documentation for config changes required to enable service.
2017-01-09 23:31:33,646  INFO  [com.pingidentity.ws.rest.oauth.client_management.filter.OAuthClientMgmtEnabledFilter] OAuth Client Management REST Web Service Attempted: service=/pf-ws/rest/oauth/clients, remote-ip=127.0.0.1, but the client management database is not enabled. Consult product documentation for config changes required to enable service.
2017-01-09 23:31:33,658  INFO  [com.pingidentity.ws.rest.oauth.client_management.filter.OAuthClientMgmtEnabledFilter] OAuth Client Management REST Web Service Attempted: service=/pf-ws/rest/oauth/clients, remote-ip=127.0.0.1, but the client management database is not enabled. Consult product documentation for config changes required to enable service.
2017-01-09 23:32:13,426 tid:aKxlAgS2121ZWpbbiOd4fn6WCy4 INFO  [org.sourceid.saml20.domain.mgmt.impl.PluginManagementSupport] Configuring plugin UserPass (org.sourceid.saml20.domain.SimpleUsernamePasswordCredentialValidator)
2017-01-09 23:32:43,956 tid:3hwAz7tzhsUoKKWNL_xQBbxwUd4 INFO  [org.sourceid.saml20.domain.mgmt.impl.PluginManagementSupport] Configuring plugin default (org.sourceid.oauth20.token.plugin.impl.ReferenceBearerAccessTokenManagementPlugin)
2017-01-10 00:07:19,810  INFO  [com.pingidentity.fsm.SessionTimeout] Application '/pingfederate' session timeout is 30 minutes.
2017-01-10 02:39:05,810  INFO  [com.pingidentity.fsm.SessionTimeout] Application '/pingfederate' session timeout is 30 minutes.
2017-01-10 03:09:22,399 tid:5hLSp5Xw-IJNCDNF0xrSbssJmX8 INFO  [org.sourceid.saml20.service.impl.localmemory.ArtifactPersistenceServiceMapImpl] Removing expired artifact ByteArrayHashKey: EC5F5B57592E6D3C485EFBF0921ECDD1CA6726D5C19BD40B2FAD9412B122 : Message{partnerRole=null, entityId='null', msg=StoredMessage{clientId='ac_client', userKeyValue='joe', scope='', return scope='false', qualifier='authz_req|HTMLFormSimplePCV', redirectUri='null', idToken='null', codeChallenge='null', codeChallengeMethod='null', tokenManagerId='null', audience='null', extendedGrantAttrs='{}', authnContextAttrs='{}'}}

Answer (score 2):

I believe the log messages you've included in this post are not relevant to the error you're hitting.

Double check that your Resource Server credentials are the same in these places:

- OAuth Playground > Settings (top right cog) > Advanced Settings > Resource Server: client_id / client_secret
- PingFederate Administration (https://pfadminhost:9999/pingfederate/app) > OAuth Settings > Clients / Manage All - find the same client_id entry and ensure it has a matching client_secret value as the playground, and that the grant types chosen include *Access Token Validation (Client is a Resource Server)*.

It should have already set this up if you used the data.zip packaged with the OAuth Playground - I suspect something has changed in your configuration afterwards.

Comment: Thanks a lot . This fixed the problem.